# Can't figure out where this mapping comes from

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

For more than a year, I have `unmap <C-X>` in my .vimrc because I can't figure out where this mapping comes from.

I used `verbose map <C-X>` as suggested in another topic, it returns

> `v  <C-X>        "*d`

and I don't know what that means. There is nothing that maps `<C-X>` to anything in my .vimrc, yet that `unmap` command doesn't even give an error, which means it's mapped somehow.

Comment: It very well could be in some startup file in VIMRUNTIME, but I’d expect to have the file shown with verbose. I have the same problem with `<BS>` in visual mode mapped to `"-d`

Comment: Does `:20verbose map <C-x>` help? Otherwise try starting Vim as `vim -V20log` and searching the `log` file for `<c-x>`.

Comment: @MartinTournoij `:20verbose map <C-X>` result is same as `verbose map <C-X>` in this case. Second method you suggested just opened an empty file. I should also note that my vim acts in same way on my secondary computer too(which uses same .vimrc).

Comment: Maybe `-V[N]{fileame}` doesn't work for older versions? See `:help starting.txt`. Otherwise you can always use: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51

Comment: @MartinTournoij I opened vim in debug mode, ignoring .vimrc and it was fine, not sure what's the problem but I'll go through my .vimrc, see what activates that mapping. Thank you very much!

Comment: I get these entries (among others) via `:verb map` and the same when running `gvim -u NONE -U NONE -N` except the first is now `v <C-X> "*d`. ```
s <C-X> "*d
v <C-Del> "*d
v <S-Del> "*d
v <C-Insert> "*y
v <S-Insert> "-d"*P
n <S-Insert> "*P
``` Despite `verbose` the source is not listed. I've searched through all files in program dir and the only instance of these mappings is in `mswin.vim`. But according to the comments in the file it needs to be explicitly sourced, and `:scriptnames` does not show the file being sourced. I logged via `-u NONE -U NONE -N -V9log.txt` and got nothing helped. I d

Comment: @Tom, I have figured out from where these mapping are coming see my [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/44218/23502). Let me know if that help :-)

Answer (score 0):

These are actually the dos standard mapping.
They are defined in the source code of Vim (`src/map.c`).

More information with [:help dos-standard-mappings](https://vimhelp.org/os_dos.txt.html#dos-standard-mappings)